# how to compare two ipv4 ranges given in CIDR format

Tags: ip, cidr

I need to write a script where two IPV4 addresses ranges(given in CIDR format) need to be compared.In overall I had to take some action on conditions such as when two IP ranges overlap, when IP ranges are identical, when one IP range contains the other. What is the best possible way to compare two IP ranges. Though,I thought to convert IP addresses into long int (32 bit)and then compare these ranges.Is this approach all fine.